# Touchpad not working at all and restart screen stuck

Tags: dual-boot, touchpad, freeze

I am using Acer nitro 5 windows10 pre installed. I downloaded Ubuntu studio18.04. As I started the installation process, my touchpad stopped responding, although the keyboard seemed  to work fine. Then I closed the installation wizard and chose the try Ubuntu option. Still the touchpad won't respond at all and the keyboard shortcuts I knew worked fine. I am a newbie and can't operate entirely through keyboard. When I tried restarting the system,  it froze on the ending  screen. I have no clue what to do. I really want to install Ubuntu studio. 
Kindly help.

Comment: I would suggest using the 'check disk for defects' option to ensure your download (of ISO) & write to install-media was flawless.  Also post-install don't forget Ubuntu Studio 18.04 was not a LTS release, so don't forget to add the PPA to get extended support.

Comment: How to add the ppa?